# Getting Error Using React Fragment <> < />

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

The Below code gives syntax error when <> </> is used

```
import React, { useEffect, useState , useRef } from 'react';


function Form() {
const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("");
const previousInputValue = useRef("");

useEffect(() => {
  previousInputValue.current = inputValue;
}, [inputValue]);

return (
  <>
    <div>
        first
    </div>
    <div>
        second
    </div>
    
  </>
);
}
```

throws error compilation failed
Syntax error: Unexpected token (13:7)

11 |
12 |     return (

> 13 |       <>
> |        ^
> 14 |         
> 15 |             first
> 16 |

Tried replacing it with div which was compiled success fully

versions :
"react": "^18.2.0",
"react-dom": "^18.2.0",
"react-scripts": "0.9.5"

I looked on their documentation if it was deprecated , but it was not. So I wonder why it id not working

Comment: You can try using `<React.Fragment>...</React.Fragment>`. I can surmise you're using older `react-script` version. Because the code is correct.

Comment: `react-scripts: 0.9.5` seems extremely old, I believe it's up to v5 now?

Comment: yes you are right, I didnot noticed that after updating react-scripts were not updated , have to do them separately

Answer (score 0):

Use export , I think it will solve your problem.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState , useRef } from 'react';


export function Form() {
const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("");
const previousInputValue = useRef("");

useEffect(() => {
  previousInputValue.current = inputValue;
}, [inputValue]);

return (
  <>
    <div>
        first
    </div>
    <div>
        second
    </div>
    
  </>
);
}
```

Comment: No this is not the issue. It is not mandatory to export a component.

Comment: yes It was not the issue